# What else to do for security in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I would like save data from user without forms, for example:

```
$car = new Car();
$car->setName($request->get('name'));
$car->setPrice($request->get('price'));

$em->persist($car);
$em->flush();
```

And next use this data and display it to other users.

So... Should I use additional PHP functions for security on save data? htmlspecialchars(), stripslashes() etc?

I know Symfony has security, but what?

I know I should validate the data, but bypassing validation what else?

Comment: Do not use raw request vars, always run them through a filter, and then validate.

Comment: Most of the frameworks already sanitize user data for you, is one of the biggest upsides of using it. Can't tell specifics about symphony (i use laravel), but still you should validate the data (like checking numbers are numbers) but not care so much about escaping characters and stuff like that.

Comment: LordNeo, basic filtration, yes, but an out of the box framework has no way of knowing your text field should be an email address for instance. So I would striptags and whitespace, any other stuff, then run it through an email address validator. Only then do you have clean and valid data.

Comment: Doesn't the symfony form component do filtering and validating?

Comment: First validate the input to make sure it's the correct data types/content. Then when you show the data for other users, you must escape the date (like using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)) to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `rules` in your Car model:

Or you can make it like this

```
Validator::make($request, [
'name' => [
    'required'
],
]);
```